# Enterprise Architect API: Create Packaging Component

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to bulk import elements into the enterprise architect. According to some reasons we structured the model using "components" which reside in "packaging components" - this means I need a script which creates "packaging components" and therein "components".
In the API there is a possibility to create Elements and Packages - with the following C# code:

Create Component:

```
Element toBeCreatedComponent = root.Elements.AddNew(name, "Component");
if (!toBeCreatedComponent.Update())
{
    Console.WriteLine(toBeCreatedComponent.GetLastError());
    System.Environment.Exit(-1);
}
root.Elements.Refresh();
```

This works fine - and for package the following code:

```
Package toBeCreatedPackage = root.Packages.AddNew(name, "Package");
if (!toBeCreatedPackage.Update())
{
    Console.WriteLine(toBeCreatedPackage.GetLastError());
    System.Environment.Exit(-1);
}
root.Elements.Refresh();
```

This works fine as well - but it creates a single package. I need a Packagin Component! I tried as type Packaging Component - but this doesn't work.
Then after a tedious search I finally found a site within the documentation where sparx described the "AddNew" API of certain objects within the Enterprise Architect Object Model - there they say: The type of package in Packages.AddNew(string name, string type) is not used.
That might be the reason why it only creates packages and nothing else.

Is there a possibility to create packaging components? Thanks upfront...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are two secret sauces to cook that dish.

1. You need to set the `SubType` to 20 after the `Update` above like

   ```
   toBeCreatedPackage.Element.SubType = 20;
   toBeCreatedPackage.Element.Update();
   ```
2. You need to reload the model view (or restart) EA or you will see just a simple package icon (though it's already a `PackagingComponent`).

   ```
   Repository.RefreshModelView (root.PackageID):
   ```